# react-native passing down routes only navigates to one route

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have the following scrollview component that displays some pages based on the following data:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    route: "MongoDB",
    bgColor: "#3FA037",
    secondary: "#4DB33D",
    fontColor: "#E8E7D5",
    animation: "none",
    style: {
      height: height * 0.1,
      resizeMode: "contain",
      top: 100,
    },
    name: require("../assets/MongoDB.png"),
  },

  {
    route: "React",
    bgColor: "#1c2c4c",
    secondary: "#7cc5d9",
    fontColor: "#1c2c4c",
    style: {
      height: height * 0.3,
      resizeMode: "contain",
    },
    animation: "rotate",
    name: require("../assets/React.png"),
  },
  {
    route: "Linux",
    bgColor: "black",
    secondary: "white",
    fontColor: "black",
    style: {
      height: height * 0.4,
      resizeMode: "contain",
    },
    animation: "none",
    name: require("../assets/NewTux.png"),
  },
];
```

The scrollview displays each object via a Page component:

```
<Animated.ScrollView
  onScroll={scrollHandler}
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
  horizontal
  style={styles.scrollContainer}
  onLayout={onLayoutRootView}
>
  <StatusBar hidden />
  {routes.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Page
        item={item}
        translateX={translateX}
        index={index}
        key={item.route}
        navigation={navigation}
        route={route}
      />
    );
  })}
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

And then the page component has a button that navigates to the item's route prop, which is a page route:

```
<Button
  style={{ backgroundColor: `${item.secondary}`, height: 75 }}
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate(item.route)}
>
  <Text style={[styles.text, { color: item.fontColor }]}>
    {item.route}
  </Text>
</Button>
```

Some weird behavior is happening and that is the button of the last page being rendered is the only one that works. In this case, it navigates to the linux component as intended but the other buttons don't do anything (not even click animation).

What's also weird is that if I rearrange the data and put mongoDB last instead of Linux, then the route will change to mongoDB. Basically, only the last button of the last page is working and navigating to the last object route prop of the data set.

I'm not sure why, I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with closures?

Here is my App, it might be a react-navigation issue:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import MongoDBQuiz from "./screens/MongoDBQuiz";
import LinuxQuiz from "./screens/LinuxQuiz";

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  MongoDB: undefined;
  Linux: undefined;
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Linux" component={LinuxQuiz} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MongoDB" component={MongoDBQuiz} />

        {/* <Stack.Screen name="React" component={} /> */}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```